# in Internet Explorer, pasteHTML causes unexpected behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML w/Javascript code (note: this only works in Internet Explorer):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changeIt() {
 var startTag = "<span class='h' id='123abc'>";
 var endTag = "</span>";
 var htmlStr = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;

 document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(startTag + htmlStr + endTag);
}
</script>
<style type='text/css'> .h { background: yellow; }</style>
<p><b>Four</b> score and seven years</p>
<input type='button' value='change' onclick='javascript:changeIt();'>
```

To use this function, simply highlight any part of the text you see in the screen, then click the "Change" button.  Now, the strange behavior:

If you highlight the word "Four" (with the bold tags) with anything else after the Four, it will make the entire highlight bold, which is not what I want.  In other words, if you highlight with your mouse:

**Four** score and seven

then click the "change" button, it will output:
****Four** score and seven**

```
<b><span class='h' id='123abc'><b>Four</b> score and seven</span></b>
```

I would like it to output this instead:
**Four** score and seven

```
<span class='h' id='123abc'><b>Four</b> score and seven</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'll take an answer in either Javascript or jQuery.

Note: seems the background color isn't show properly on here, but my point is the whole selection turns bold when I don't want it to.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything on my machine (IE8).

Comment: Try again; I just re-edited the code and tested it again on IE8 myself.  Make sure you highlight some text first then click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a `TextRange`, which you are in the example, you can use its built-in `execCommand` method for many formatting tasks. For the background colour example, it would be the following:

```
function changeIt() {
    document.selection.createRange().execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
}
```

Note: this example is IE only.

Comment: This works great for this example, and exactly what I was looking for, however, what if I wanted to add a class and id to the <span> instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  This was an excellent catalyst to get me working on my own solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hiya James. You mention this was a catalyst to you working out your own solution. Could you post your solution for the rest of us?